# CompletableFuture already completed with an exception

Tags: java, exception, completable-future

[CompletableFuture.completedFuture()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#completedFuture-U-) returns a `CompletedFuture` that is already completed with the given value.

How do we construct a `CompletableFuture` that is already completed exceptionally?

Meaning, instead of returning a value I want the future to throw an exception.

Comment: In which context do you need to do that? I think in a lot of contexts, just throwing the exception would do the job (e.g. with Spring `@Async` or with `thenCompose()`)

Comment: @DidierL I've got a method that executes quick tasks synchronously, but returns a `CompletionStage`. Why? Because the caller wants to validate input parameters synchronously before chaining asynchronous `CompletionStage`s after it, and it needs any exceptions thrown by precondition validation to get handled by `exceptionally()`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Unlike Java 9 and later, Java 8 does not provide a static factory method for this scenario.  The default constructor can be used instead:

```
CompletableFuture<T> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
future.completeExceptionally(exception);
```

Answer (score 16):

Java 9 provides [`CompletableFuture.failedFuture​(Throwable ex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#failedFuture-java.lang.Throwable-) that does exactly that.