# Throwing exceptions from sync portions of async methods returning CompletableFuture

Tags: java, asynchronous, exception, completable-future

This question is specific to Java and `CompletableFuture`.

If I have an async method like the one below,

```
CompletableFuture<String> get() {
    /* Step #1: Do some sync prep work */
    String s = doSomethingSync();

    /* Step #2: Do something async (returning CompletableFuture) */
    return doSomethingAsync(s);
}
```

If code in step #1 throws, callers of `get()` will get an exception before getting the `CompletableFuture` it returns, whereas if code inside the `CompletableFuture` returned in step #2 throws, callers will only get an exception when they interact with the returned `CompletableFuture`.

This suggests that callers of `get()` should write some intricate exception handling code to tackle both cases.

Here's an example of another async method, `invokeGet()`, that invokes `get()` and returns the length of the `String` it returns:

```
CompletableFutre<Integer> InvokeGet() {
    try {
        CompletableFuture future = get();
        return furure.handle((result, throwable) -> {
           if (throwable != null) {
               /* Handle exception thrown in step #2 in get(), e.g. rethrow */
           } else {
               return result.length();
           }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        /* Handle exception thrown in step #1 in get() */
        /* Return some value or throw */
    }
}
```

My question is:

Is `get()` poorly written because it requires its callers to do this kind of intricate exception handling, or is this a usual and common pattern? Should async methods returning `CompletableFuture`s confine themselves to returning faulted futures in case of errors so their callers don't have to write such error-handling code?

Comment: Create a `CompletableFuture` that either succeeds or is in error for the first part of your work. `thenApplyAsync` the async part. `return`. I would expect a method that returns a `CompletableFuture` to return one in an error condition if there is an error - I would not expect it to throw. Is short: yes it is badly written, and yes they should return faulted futures.

Comment: Also, any code that has `throws Exception` or `catch (Exception e)` is inherently wrong. Catching _all_ exceptions is always a very bad idea.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Even if it rethrows or wraps-and-throws?

Comment: Would would you do with a `NullPointerException` rewrapped?

Comment: I see. This code snippet was only meant for illustrative purposes but I remain grateful for the additional useful input.

Answer (score 0):

In short, it depends on your own implementation but it could be improved. Having the calling thread handle the exception could be beneficial in a case where you want to ignore, log, or react to the exception through a different thread (basic example [here](https://gist.github.com/marccarre/2439456da4b63dfb0c2e931ce1204b01)). However, a lot of *patterns* (seen in [this posts answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44409962/throwing-exception-from-completablefuture)) I've seen would have you contain the `async` function with a `try-catch-block` and re-throw a more *useful to your application* exception to be handled by the parent thread which I think is a bit better.

If you are looking for different exception handling, see this [article](https://grokonez.com/java/java-8/java-8-completablefuture-handle-exception#I_Ways_to_handle_exception) for examples of different handling.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is appropriate to throw exceptions for argument validation, as the caller is not supposed to handle those – an illegal argument is a bug that has to be fixed.

However it is probably best to put other exceptions inside the returned `CompletableFuture`, so that the caller can use the standard `CompletableFuture` exception handling and chaining. Similarly, you wouldn't return a `null` future but a future completed with `null`. See also [CompletableFuture already completed with an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49116855/525036).